# ¿Cómo puedo ver los usuarios y sus respectivos permisos que tengo en mi base de datos en Posgresql a traves de Ubuntu de Windows?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ubuntu, django-models

Actualmente, me encuentro enfrentando un problema en mi aplicación que parece estar relacionado con los permisos de mi base de datos. Para investigar y solucionar este inconveniente, necesito obtener información detallada sobre los usuarios y los permisos que tienen asignados en la base de datos.

He revisado los registros de errores y mensajes de la aplicación, pero no proporcionan suficiente información para identificar la causa raíz. Por lo tanto, me gustaría conocer qué usuarios tienen acceso a qué tablas y qué tipos de permisos tienen asignados. Específicamente, quiero verificar si alguno de los usuarios tiene permisos insuficientes que podrían estar causando el error.

Si alguien pudiera proporcionarme una consulta SQL o alguna otra forma de obtener esta información, estaría muy agradecido. También, si conocen otras posibles causas para el error que estoy enfrentando, les agradecería que las compartieran. Cualquier ayuda será bienvenida, ya que estoy ansioso por resolver este problema y mejorar la seguridad y funcionalidad de mi aplicación. ¡Gracias de antemano por su amable asistencia!

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "hola"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 220, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 218, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "hola"
```

Comment: ¿puedes compartir tu archivo de settings?

Comment: el settings.py lo dejo en una respuesta de la pregunta